# Unable to create express MVC app

Tags: node.js, express

I tried installing `express-mvc-generator` using the following command and it was installed successfully.

```
sudo npm install express-mvc-generator -g 
[sudo] password for anil: 
/usr/local/bin/express >/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-mvc-generator/bin/express
/usr/local/lib
`-- express-mvc-generator@2.2.4
```

But when I use `express app`.

I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node\r’: No such file or directory
```

I do not know how to solve it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an issue with the file format. In terminal, if you do the following:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-mvc-generator/bin
vi express
:set ff=unix
enter key
:x
enter key
```

Then that should solve your issue.